# CoreData import overload memory

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift, core-data

I have some master data, which are JSON files and I need to import by using CoreData. Transaction point is when all masters insert normally. However, the amount of use of memory is increasing until commit. The app crash due to the overload memory before commit.

I'm thinking two solutions like below.

1. Use SQLite's function like saving data to file temporary. (I'm not sure whether the function exists or not.)
2. Use two DB file. One is for operation and another one is temporal. If import is done normally, replace from temporal to the operation DB.

But still not sure about it. Does anyone know any solutions in this case? Thanks.

Update1:

> So you're importing into an empty data store, or you're adding to existing data that you need to revert to on failure?

In my case, this is the process below.

1. Delete existing data. (All tables)
2. Importing into an empty data.
3. After master data is done, commit it. If something error happen, rollback transaction. The deleting and importing are reverted so that to ensure consistency between master data.

> Also, why do much data on a mobile device?

My customer's need.

Update2:

I tried disable  undoManager but the result was not effected so much. I do not need "undo" but I need rollback. In this case, setUndoManager is available...?

```
[[self managedObjectContext] setUndoManager:nil] ;
```

Comment: So you're importing into an empty data store, or you're adding to existing data that you need to revert to on failure? Also, why do much data on a mobile device?

Comment: @Wain Thanks for your comment. I edited my question. At first delete all data and then import into the empty data.

Comment: Have you considered batching your imports? Then you could save each batch in the one private MOC, which when complete could persist to disc on another private MOC that is attached to the persistent store coordinator.

Comment: @andrewbuilder Thanks. I did not know that. Could you share me more details or reference url? I want to elaborate it.

Comment: If I remember worrectly (when I used CoreData), the UndoManager is in fact disabled by default on iOS.

Comment: @Nicolas Buquet Thanks for the valuable information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoreData is memory hungry.

Its context (the scratchpad) is stored in memory.

If you can work with 2 db files, store your new data in a new file and save and flush regularly (like every 1000 records, depending on your record's size) to maintain your memory consumption acceptable.
if there is an error at import, simply close and delete the new db file.

You can also work on the initial db file with adding a field to your records that can be a `"validated": boolean` or a `"timestamp": date`.
The new records have a validated filed to false. If you encounter an error, delete all records that are not "validated" (or on date, delete all records whose "timestamp" is after the date of the beginning of the import).

But, in the second solution, you need to not delete all records at once, because if you make a request to get all records whose "validated" is false, all your new records will be instantiated in scratchpad (that's the way CoreData works) and that will again consume a lot of memory.

Comment: Thanks, I've never thought about the second solution. I'm now checking which is better in my case.